# How to apply all options, filters, sorts from one datasource to another in kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

So I know there must be a better way to do this than how I am currently doing it.  I have a kendo type page where users can sort and filter and such.  By digging into the dataSource object I found enough info to extract the sorts and filters and apply them to a new dataSource I create so I can send it to server to make an excel file with.  Now I only have to get the formatting that has been applied as well.  Here is what I have so far.

```
dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
filters = dataSource.filter();
sorts = dataSource.sort();
options = dataSource.options;//not sure if this is what I need
allData = dataSource.data();
query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);
kendoDataSource = query;        

if(filters && sorts) {
    kendoDataSource = kendoDataSource.filter(filters).sort(sorts).data;
}else if(filters) {
    kendoDataSource = kendoDataSource.filter(filters).data;
}else if(sorts) {
    kendoDataSource = kendoDataSource.sort(sorts).data;
}else{
    kendoDataSource = kendoDataSource.data;
}
```

This allows me to iterate through the kendoDataSource array and stringify every value of the array - which is a json object - giving me exactly what the user sees in terms of filters and sorts.  However the date fields have some formatting applied to them in the original dataSource and not sure how to programmatically apply all those formatting options in javascript/jQuery.